# Is it dangerous to serve executable cgi files in public folder?

Tags: web-application, webserver, web-service

In the past, Apache used to serve cgi files from `cgi-bin` folder only, and it was always advised to avoid putting executable files in public folders. However, today's webservers fairly serve executable cgi file from everywhere.

What is the security risk for serving webpages directly from executable cgi files? For example, what is the risk for `http://example.com/hello.cgi` where executable file of hello.cgi is in the root (public) directory? (comparing with a non-executable PHP file of hello.php)?

Of course, cgi scripts are practically served via FastCGI to persist the connection, but does it have an better security too?

Answer (score 2):

In short, separating CGI files, which are often scripts, makes it easier to ensure that the web server will never mistakenly return the text of the script to the client instead of executing the CGI and returning the results.  If the script "source code" is revealed to the client, it may expose sensitive information, such as embedded database connection passwords or just information about how the script executes that could be abused by an attacker.

For example, the entire /cgi-bin directory is usually configured to execute files and never to return content.  If you edit `hello.cgi` and leave an editor backup file `hello.cgi~` behind, the server should never return that file as content if /cgi-bin is configured correctly.  On the other hand, if that backup file is sitting in a normal web root that serves files, then the magic mapping of ".cgi -> execute" won't take effect for the `hello.cgi~` file, and the server may therefore return the content of `hello.cgi~` instead of executing it.

Comment: I totally agree with the risk issues you quoted, but can't we overcome by `include` the actual code? I mean having `hello.cgi` with no code except including the actual code which is outside the public folders. Thus, upon a failure in webserver, nothing will be exposed except the full path to the actual script (which is inaccessible).

Comment: If by this you mean having a file shell in the webroot which simply `include`s another file outside the webroot, you *could* do that, but it's more complex than simply segregating your scripts into a /cgi-bin directory with strict controls.

Comment: Also, to complicate the matter, newer languages like PHP permit you to mingle code and content within the same file, which was a major impetus for the shift away from /cgi-bin to inclusion of scripts within the webroot.  So another aspect of the answer is "...and it used to make more sense, in the old days."

Comment: I am not against the idea of `cgi-bin`, but the point is that I use `nginx` not `Apache`, and the implementation of `cgi-bin` is not common in `nginx` or I am not aware of that.